# CATransition not working in UITabBarController (but is working elsewhere)

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, catransition

I'm trying to implement a CATransition in a UITabBarController. Right now, I have a class called `FeedViewController`. Each tab in the UITabBarController is an instance of this class. In each tab view controller (`FirstViewController`, `SecondViewController`, etc) I have code along the lines of:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    FeedViewController *feedViewController = [[FeedViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FeedViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self addChildViewController: feedViewController];
    feedViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,self.view.frame.size.height);
    [self.view addSubview: feedViewController.view];
    [feedViewController didMoveToParentViewController: self];
}
```

Now in `FeedViewController` I have an IBAction which presents a new view controller. This is the code:

```
-(IBAction)goHome {
    HomeViewController *home = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    [animation setDuration:0.3];
    [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
    [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];
    [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
    [[self.view.superview layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SwitchToView"];
    [self presentViewController:home animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

I've used the exact same CATransition code in other parts of my app before, and it is working fine there. **However, in this case there is no animation when the new view is presented.** I believe the problem to be the layer where I am adding the animation. Specifically, I believe that I need to replace `[self.view.superview layer]` with something else, but I don't know what.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

**Update:**

If I change the `animated:NO` to `animated:YES` in the above code, the CATransition does work (but occurs at the same time as the default sliding up animation). This occurs in both iOS 6 and iOS 7.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish, and what is actually happening?

Comment: @matt I want a horizontal sliding animation when the user clicks the button. Right now, I am getting no animation (the new view is still presented) despite the CATransition code I have.

Comment: so this has nothing to do with the tab bar controller, right? The question you're asking is: the user taps a button, and you present a presented view controller by sliding it from one side? Is that correct? You're just trying to customize the presentation transition animation?

Comment: @matt I believe it does have to do with the tab bar controller, because it is working fine when done with two single layer view controllers. In this case, the transition code is in `FeedViewController`, and `FeedViewController` is initiated into each tab bar view controller (`FirstViewController` ,`SecondViewController`, etc). This process involves adding `FeedViewController` as a subview, and then moving it to the parent  view controller.

Comment: On iPhone, presentation is always at the top level. Maybe you should be using a custom container and _no_ presentation (in which case you are totally in charge of the transition).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the iPhone, a presented view controller always occupies top level. This means that if you say `presentViewController:...` the new view controller's view replaces the tab bar controller. If that isn't what you want - that is, if you want to perform a transition animation *inside a tab* - then you will need either to use a view and a transition without the `presentViewController:...` or else, if you want to use a view controller, then use a custom container controller (and a transition, again without the `presentViewController`), as I do here:

https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch06p316containerController/ch19p631containerController/ViewController.m

If, on the other hand, you are aiming to replacing the whole tab bar controller with a different view controller, then the way to customize that transition in a way that's available on both iOS and iOS 7 is to use a custom container controller as your ultimate root view controller. Now the transition is up to you. That, for example, is what I do in my Albumen app. This consists of three navigation controllers in sequence; tapping a button proceeds to the next navigation controller. Clearly we do not want to use `presentViewController:` because they will all just pile up on each other; we want to replace the whole navigation controller by another. The structure is similar to the code I just pointed you to; the Ultimate Controller's view occupies the whole screen, and when it is handed a new child view controller it does a transition from its previous child view controller's view to the new child view controller's view, also occupying the whole screen (as a total subview of its own view, don't you see).

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in this direction. I don't have a fully implemented solution yet but you've provided me with some guidance that I can use to solve my problem.